# POST Request works in Insomnia/Postman, but not python request

Tags: python, proxy, dns, request

I am trying to reverse engineer an API at work, I have managed to get a successful 200 response in both Insomnia and Postman. When I take the code generated by Insomnia or Post man and add my companies proxy and .pem certificate, I receive a response in HTML basically saying the following:

> Host Not Resolvable
> The Host is not resolvable.
>
> DNS is unable to resolve the requested host. This is not a proxy
> issue. Please test the host resolution from a mobile device or
> personal pc to see if you experience the issue outside of the COMPANY
> network.
>
> Rule: SSL Tunnel: Bypass Sites(Handle CONNECT Call)

Here is my python code:

```
PROXY_ADDRESS = "proxy.company.com"
PROXY_PORT = "8080"
PROXY_USERNAME = "************"
PROXY_PASSWORD = "************"

import requests

proxy = {
    "http": f"http://{PROXY_USERNAME}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@{PROXY_ADDRESS}:{PROXY_PORT}",
    "https": f"http://{PROXY_USERNAME}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@{PROXY_ADDRESS}:{PROXY_PORT}"
}

url = {CORRECT URL GENORATED BY INSOMNIA}

payload = {CORRECT PAYLOAD GENORATED BY INSOMNIA}
headers = {
    {CORRECT HEADERS GENORATED BY INSOMNIA (includes user agent and cookie)}
}

r = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, verify='COMPANYRootCA.pem')

# Used to see the html that was returning (it should just return JSON like it does in insomnia or post man)
f = open("home.html", "a")
f.write(r.text)
f.close()

print(r.json) # Outputs: <bound method Response.json of <Response [502]>>
```

Again, the thing that has me baffled is that it works fine in Insomnia or Postman, I get the JSON response with no issues. I know the proxy is working because if I do `requests.get('https://www.google.com', proxies=proxy, verify='COMPANYRootCA.pem')` it will return the valid HTML response for Google's homepage

Comment: As the error comes from the company proxy you use, you may probably need to ask them what is happening. The error message says that the proxy is unable to resolve the name you want to connect to (which is why the proxy may be completely working for other names but maybe not that one; as for Postman working you are not telling if it uses the proxy too or not)

Comment: @PatrickMevek yes sorry, in postman I have not manually set any proxy settings, it just uses the default (which I would have believed to be the same ones)

Comment: " in postman I have not manually set any proxy settings" and that works and when you use the corporate proxy it doesn't work, so I think it shows clearly your next step to come closer to people running that proxy and debug the issue with them... There is probably nothing wrong in your code per se. There could be local policies on the proxy prohibiting the traffic you are trying to have...

Answer (score 0):

It seems requests are including some information that server are not accpeting.
I used urlib3 and solve my problem